# Changed Liferay's language, restarted, created new site: LocaleUtil.getSiteDefault() still en_US

Tags: liferay, locale, liferay-7

I added this to my `portal-ext.properties` then restarted my Liferay 7:

```
user.country=JP
user.language=ja
```

Then I switched the default language to Japanese in `Control Panel > Instance Settings > Miscellaneous > Display Settings` too just in case.

Then I created a new site, the UI appeared directly with the Japanese flag first, which is great:

[image: Liferay site Japanese]

**But** then I deployed and ran this simple module from Gogo Shell:

```
log.info("LocaleUtil.getSiteDefault(): " + LocaleUtil.getSiteDefault());
```

Result:

```
LocaleUtil.getSiteDefault(): en_US
```

Why is it not `ja_JP`?
How to fix it?

Comment: user.country and user.language are system properties as per comments in liferay src files. Have you tried overriding this properties in system-ext.properties instead of portal-ext.properties. ?

Comment: @PankajKathiriya: Thank you for your suggestion. I set `user.country=JP` and `user.language=ja` in `portal-ext.properties` and restarted Tomcat. Unfortunately it leads to the same result.

Comment: I have just tried setting Locale from Control Panel the way you did and I was able to get correct locale while executing  LocaleUtil.getSiteDefault() ? It seems an issue related to your version of Liferay. Mine is LR7sp3.

Comment: @PankajKathiriya: I am on 7010 service pack 3 patch level de-21-7010

Comment: I was on de-14-7010 and applied patch to be on de-21-7010. I am able to get correct locale value.

Comment: did you tried changing values of `company.default.locale=ja_JP,en_US`
`company.default.time.zone=<your/timezone>` and `locales=ja_JP,en_US`
in any portal-*.properties file used by liferay